# Search through array and add missing months and years to original array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with financial year and month(June -July) converted to calendar year and month. Each row contain financial year, financial month, calendar year, calendar month and money spent in that month. This array is returned by SQL query. When it is returned it doesn't include months where money spent was zero.

I want to find the calendar months starting from first calendar year(in this case 2017) where money spent was zero and add them to the same array with its corresponding financial year, financial month, calendar year, calendar month. So that array contains all the months where money spent was whether zero or more than zero.

The array returned from database is created as $row here. I tried to create a logic for finding months but wasn't successful. In my case the loops rather than outputting less than 36 times, outputs numerous values. Any help would be realy great.

```
    $row;
$row[0]=array("fin_year"=>2018,"fin_month"=>5,"spent"=>125.00,"cal_year"=>2017,"cal_month"=>11 );
$row[1] = array("fin_year" => 2018, "fin_month" => 7, "spent" => 200.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 1);
$row[2] = array("fin_year" => 2018, "fin_month" => 8, "spent" => 300.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 2);
$row[3] = array("fin_year" => 2018, "fin_month" => 10, "spent" => 200.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 4);
$row[4] = array("fin_year" => 2018, "fin_month" => 12, "spent" => 200.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 6);
$row[5] = array("fin_year" => 2019, "fin_month" => 2, "spent" => 725.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 8);
$row[6] = array("fin_year" => 2019, "fin_month" => 3, "spent" => 210.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 9);
$row[7] = array("fin_year" => 2019, "fin_month" => 4, "spent" => 330.00, "cal_year" => 2018, "cal_month" => 10);
$row[8] = array("fin_year" => 2019, "fin_month" => 8, "spent" => 230.00, "cal_year" => 2019, "cal_month" => 4);
$row[9] = array("fin_year" => 2019, "fin_month" => 10, "spent" => 333.00, "cal_year" => 2019, "cal_month" => 4);

echo "<pre>";print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";

$start_year = 2017;
$last_year = 2019;
for ($l = $start_year; $l++; $l<=$last_year){   //check first year              2017
    foreach ($row as $value) {                  //loop through all rows         row['0']
        if ($l = $value['cal_year']) {          //                              true
        for ($k=1;$k<=12;$k++){                 //k=12  months of year
                if ($k != $value['cal_month']) {
                    echo 'kkkkk' . $l . $k;
                    echo '<br>';
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add how the array should look like after that? `$start_year` and `$last_year` are static?

Answer (score 0):

This script loops through every year between `$start_year` and `$last_year`, then through every `month` between `1` and `12`. If there is no entry in your array with these both parameters, it will add one at the end of your array. Finally it sorts your array by `fin_year` and `fin_month`.

```
$row = array(); // YOUR ARRAY FROM DATABASE

$start_year = 2017;
$last_year = 2019;

// loops through every year between $start_year and $last_year
for( $current_year = $start_year; $current_year <= $last_year; $current_year++ ) {
  // loops through every month between 1 and 12
  for( $current_month = 1; $current_month <= 12; $current_month++ ) {
    // loops through every item of your array
    $found = false;
    foreach( $row as $value ) {
      // if there is an entry with that year and month, it breaks the foreach
      if( $value['fin_year'] == $current_year && $value['fin_month'] == $current_month )  {
        $found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if( !$found )  {
      // if there was no entry found with that year and month, it will add a new one at the end
      $row[] = array("fin_year" => $current_year, "fin_month" => $current_month, "spent" => 0, "cal_year" => $current_year, "cal_month" => $current_month );
      $found = false;
    }
  }
}

// function to sort the array by fin_year and if equal by fin_month
function special_sort($a, $b) {
  $retval = $a['fin_year'] <=> $b['fin_year'];
  if ($retval == 0) {
    $retval = $a['fin_month'] <=> $b['fin_month'];
  }
  return $retval;
}

// call the sort function
usort($row, 'special_sort');

// displays your new array
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $row );
```